# HTTP Post giving 200, but no data arriving. Exception handling

Tags: angularjs, api, django-rest-framework

I can see in my terminal (testing locally) that the "post" is happening. But the data never arrives. In the browser, it tells gives me a 200, but the response is my exception error ("Not working").

How can I get the data to actually *post* to my database? Or please suggest some error/exception handling to try and local the problem.

When testing, this works fine:

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/api/item/291/', {'uid':21, 'click':1, 'like':1, 'image':0, 'scroll':1, 'clickbuy':0})
```

Rest_views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from django.http import JsonResponse
import datetime
import json

def add_analytic(product, user, like, click, image, scroll, clickbuy):
    Analytic(product=product, user=user, like=like, click=click, image=image, scroll=scroll, clickbuy=clickbuy).save()

class ProductItemView(views.ObjectGetMixin, views.BaseObjectView):
    model = Product
    mapper_class = mappers.ProductMapper

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            add_analytic(
                product=Product.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk']), 
                user=User.objects.get(id=request.POST['uid']),
                like=int(request.POST['like']),
                click=int(request.POST['click']),
                image=int(request.POST['image']),
                scroll=int(request.POST['scroll']),
                clickbuy=int(request.POST['clickbuy']))
            return JsonResponse({'IT': 'WORKED'})
        except Exception:
            return JsonResponse({'Result': 'Not working'})
```

AngularJS:

```
.factory('cardsApi', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var like = JSON.stringify({'uid':21, 'click':1, 'like':1, 'image':0, 'scroll':1, 'clickbuy':0});

        var postRecordlikes = function (product_id) {
            $http({
                url: ('http://localhost:8000/item/' + product_id + "/"),
                dataType: 'json',
                method: 'POST',
                data: like,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
        })
        }

        return {
            postRecordLikes: postRecordLikes,
        };
    }])

    .controller('CardsCtrl', ['$scope', 'TDCardDelegate', 'cardsApi', '$http',
        function ($scope, TDCardDelegate, cardsApi, $http) {
            console.log('CARDS CTRL');
            $scope.cards = []

            $scope.cardSwipedRight = function (card) {
                console.log('RIGHT');
                postRecordLikes(card);
            };


            var postRecordLikes = function (product_id) {
                cardsApi.postRecordLikes(product_id)
                    .then(function successCallback(product_id) {

                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
            };

        }
    ])
```

And Chrome network inspector's result:

[image]

Comment: I see you passing dislike variable as data, but I found no dislike variable in code. Isn't it supposed the "like" in here ?

Comment: That was a typo- fixed it up. Could it be that I need to change "views.ObjectGetMixin" to "views.ObjectPostMixin"? If so- how can I do this?

Comment: It would be useful to pass details of exception to the response

Comment: @JohnPoison, please show me how I would pass the details of the response to the exception

Answer (score -1):

Try to work with `request.data` to access to your data :

```
class ProductItemView(views.ObjectGetMixin, views.BaseObjectView):
    model = Product
    mapper_class = mappers.ProductMapper

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            add_analytic(
                product=Product.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk']), 
                user=User.objects.get(id=request.data['uid']),
                like=int(request.data['like']),
                click=int(request.data['click']),
                image=int(request.data['image']),
                scroll=int(request.data['scroll']),
                clickbuy=int(request.data['clickbuy']))
            return JsonResponse({'IT': 'WORKED'})
        except Exception:
            return JsonResponse({'Result': 'Not working'})
```

Comment: Thank you, but this did not work. Have I told anywhere in my rest_views that the data its' receiving is json? I'm not sure

Comment: Normally you don't have to specify it. But as @JohnPoison said, you're sending dislike as data, but the var you're binding the JSON document to is like. Maybe the issue comes from that.

Comment: That dislike/like was a typo. How can I tell rest views to expect json?

Comment: Rest framework examines the Content-Type header sent in the incoming request to determine which parser to use. If you want to allow it only to expect JSON content, add 'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser' to the set of default parsers. See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#setting-the-parsers for more infos.